# How to see where inbound network traffic is coming from? (node.js/express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, networking, railway

I'm trying to utilize railway's new app sleeping feature which puts your active deployment to sleep after 10 minutes of no outbound network activity. It will then wake up your server on any inbound traffic, so that your app can still be accessed but you aren't getting charged while it's inactive.

I'm having the issue that my server constantly has a small amount of background inbound traffic, preventing it from being able to stay asleep when inactive. There are no incoming HTTP requests, and I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out where the traffic is coming from but I'm at a loss. Does anybody have an ideas? It's a very simple app, so I'm not sure what's going on here. I would really like to be able to utilize app sleeping with railway if possible.

[image: My server's network usage via railway]

I've tried disabling the public domain to see if that would stop the inbound traffic, but the network usage remained the same. I've also googled for hours on end trying to figure out where this traffic could be coming from, and I've had no luck at all. Please help!!

Comment: You'll probably need to use a packet capture application like `tcpdump`. I don't know anytihng about railway, so I don't know if that's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the 'ipinfo' library, it should be able to do most if not all of what you are attempting to do :)